# Weighted Average Cost in POWER QUERY

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Im new to power query and Im trying to calqulate Weighted Average Cost of materials.

When I receive a new stock, avarage price shoul be (Cost of Available Stock + Cost of New Stock) / Total Stock (Qty)

When we issue stock, the average price should be Cost of Available Stock  / Available Stock (Qty)

I have following example table.

[image: Sample Table]

Is there any idea how to calculate the weighted average cost in this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: And what are the sample outputs based on your sample input and how do you calculate them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `List.Generate` function to generate both the Running Total Column as well as the Weighted Average Cost column.

***Starting with:***
[image]

***M Code***

```
let

//Change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Type", type text}, 
        {"In Price", Currency.Type}, {"Qty", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Capitalized Each Word" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Type", Text.Proper, type text}}),
    #"Add Running Total Column" = 
        Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(#"Capitalized Each Word") &
            {List.Generate(
                ()=>[rt=#"Capitalized Each Word"[Qty]{0}, idx=0],
                each [idx] < Table.RowCount(#"Capitalized Each Word"),
                each [rt = [rt] + #"Capitalized Each Word"[Qty]{[idx]+1}, idx=[idx]+1],
                each [rt])},
            type table[Date=date, Type=text, In Price=Currency.Type, Qty=Int64.Type, Running Total=Int64.Type]),

    #"Add Avg Cost Column" = 
        Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(#"Add Running Total Column") & 
            {List.Generate(
                ()=>[cst=if #"Add Running Total Column"[Type]{0}="In" then #"Add Running Total Column"[In Price]{0} else null, idx=0],
                each [idx] < Table.RowCount(#"Add Running Total Column"),
                each [cst=if #"Add Running Total Column"[Type]{[idx]+1}="Out" then [cst]
                    else ((if [cst]=null then 0 else [cst]) * #"Add Running Total Column"[Running Total]{[idx]} + 
                        #"Add Running Total Column"[In Price]{[idx]+1} * #"Add Running Total Column"[Qty]{[idx]+1})
                        / #"Add Running Total Column"[Running Total]{[idx]+1} , idx=[idx]+1],
                each [cst])},
        type table[Date=date, Type=text, In Price=Currency.Type, Qty=Int64.Type, Running Total=Int64.Type, Avg Cost=Currency.Type])        
in
    #"Add Avg Cost Column"
```

***results***
[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, Thank you. It is working perfectly. I have one more question related to this . If I have more than one material as below table how can I calculate Average cost for each material. 

Date Material Type In Price Qty
01.01.2022 A   In               2 1000
02.01.2022 A Out                  -200
15.01.2022 A Out                  -300
03.02.2022 A In               3 1000
08.02.2022 A Out                  -500
10.02.2022 A Out                  -100
11.02.2022 A Out                  -200
12.02.2022 B In               4 1500
15.02.2022 B Out                   -500

Thank you

Comment: @DineshSuranga That is a separate question.  However, one way would be to `Group` by material, and then use this same algorithm on each group.

Comment: Hi Ron, I grouped table by Material and tried to add Running total and Average columns. But it show me errors. Could you please help me to sort this out.

Comment: @DineshSuranga Not in comments. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

The full script power query for multiple items :

let
//Change next line to reflect your actual data source
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="PMP_5"]}[Content],

```
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, 
    {"In Price", Currency.Type}, {"Qty", Int64.Type}, {"ItemID", type text}}),

#"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Date", Order.Ascending}, {"Qty", Order.Descending}}),

#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"ItemID"}, {
    {"All", each _, type table [Date=date, Type=text, In Price=Currency.Type, Qty=Int64.Type, ItemID=text]}
}),

#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each let
currentTable = [All],
#"Add Running Total Column" = 
    Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(currentTable) &
        {List.Generate(
            ()=>[rt=currentTable[Qty]{0}, idx=0],
            each [idx] < Table.RowCount(currentTable),
            each [rt = [rt] + currentTable[Qty]{[idx]+1}, idx=[idx]+1],
            each [rt])},
        type table[Date=date, In Price=Currency.Type, Qty=Int64.Type, ItemID=text, Running Total=Int64.Type]),

#"Add Avg Cost Column" = 
    Table.FromColumns(
        Table.ToColumns(#"Add Running Total Column") & 
        {List.Generate(
            ()=>[cst=if currentTable[Qty]{0}>0 then #"Add Running Total Column"[In Price]{0} else null, idx=0],
            each [idx] < Table.RowCount(#"Add Running Total Column"),
            each [cst=if currentTable[Qty]{[idx]+1}<0 then [cst]
                else ((if [cst]=null then 0 else [cst]) * #"Add Running Total Column"[Running Total]{[idx]} + 
                    #"Add Running Total Column"[In Price]{[idx]+1} * #"Add Running Total Column"[Qty]{[idx]+1})
                    / #"Add Running Total Column"[Running Total]{[idx]+1} , idx=[idx]+1],
            each [cst])},
        type table[Date=date, In Price=Currency.Type, Qty=Int64.Type, ItemID=text, Running Total=Int64.Type, Avg Cost=Currency.Type])
```

in
#"Add Avg Cost Column"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"All"}),

```
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", {"Date", "In Price", "Qty", "Running Total", "Avg Cost"}, {"Date", "In Price", "Qty", "Running Total", "Avg Cost"}),
#"Rounded Off" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom",{{"Avg Cost", each Number.Round(_, 2), type number}})
```

in
#"Rounded Off"

Comment: the source table is Without the "Type" Column