# Weighted Average Cost in POWER QUERY with Group

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm new to power query and I'm trying to calculate Running Qty and Weighted Average Cost for **each material**.

I have following data table.

[image: Data Table]

I need to add Running Qty column and Average cost column in to table.

When receive a stock, average price should be (Cost of Available Stock + Cost of New Stock) / Total Stock (Qty)
and
When issue a stock, the average price should be Cost of Available Stock / Available Stock (Qty)

Is there any idea how to calculate the running qty and weighted average cost for **each material** separately?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in your [previous similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72670150/weighted-average-cost-in-power-query), you can

- Group by material
- then apply the same algorithm to each group

To ***apply the same algorithm***, one simple method is to

- convert the previous code into a function
- call that function from the `Table.Group` aggregation section
- and a few changes are made in order to account for the extra column

*The code assumes entries are in date order as shown in your sample. If they are not, you will need to add some sorting steps*

***Source Data***
[image]

***Function M Code***
*Add as a blank query*
*Rename `fnRT_AP`*

```
//rename fnRT_AP

(tbl as table)=>

let
    #"Add Running Total Column" = 
        Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(tbl) &
            {List.Generate(
                ()=>[rt=tbl[Qty]{0}, idx=0],
                each [idx] < Table.RowCount(tbl),
                each [rt = [rt] + tbl[Qty]{[idx]+1}, idx=[idx]+1],
                each [rt])},
            type table[Date=date, Material=text, Type=text, In Price=Currency.Type, Qty=Int64.Type, Running Total=Int64.Type]),

    #"Add Avg Cost Column" = 
        Table.FromColumns(
            Table.ToColumns(#"Add Running Total Column") & 
            {List.Generate(
                ()=>[cst=if #"Add Running Total Column"[Type]{0}="In" then #"Add Running Total Column"[In Price]{0} else null, idx=0],
                each [idx] < Table.RowCount(#"Add Running Total Column"),
                each [cst=if #"Add Running Total Column"[Type]{[idx]+1}="Out" then [cst]
                    else ((if [cst]=null then 0 else [cst]) * #"Add Running Total Column"[Running Total]{[idx]} + 
                        #"Add Running Total Column"[In Price]{[idx]+1} * #"Add Running Total Column"[Qty]{[idx]+1})
                        / #"Add Running Total Column"[Running Total]{[idx]+1} , idx=[idx]+1],
                each [cst])},
        type table[Date=date, Material=text, Type=text, In Price=Currency.Type, Qty=Int64.Type, Running Total=Int64.Type, Avg Cost=Currency.Type])        
in
    #"Add Avg Cost Column"
```

***Main Code***

```
let

//Change next line to reflect your actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table11"]}[Content],
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Material", type text}, {"Type", type text}, 
        {"In Price", Currency.Type}, {"Qty", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Capitalized Each Word" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Type", Text.Proper, type text}}),

    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Capitalized Each Word", {"Material"}, {
        {"rtap", each fnRT_AP(_), 
            type table[Date=date, Material=text, Type=text, In Price=Currency.Type, Qty=Int64.Type, Running Total=Int64.Type, Avg Cost=Currency.Type]}
        }),

    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Material"}),
    #"Expanded rtap" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "rtap", {"Date", "Material", "Type", "In Price", "Qty", "Running Total", "Avg Cost"})
in
    #"Expanded rtap"
```

***Results***
[image]

Comment: Hi Ron,
Thank you for answer.
It gives me correct Running total, but some cell have null in Avg Cost.

Date Material Type In Price Qty Running Total  Avg Cost 
1/01/2022 A In  2 1000 1000 
2/01/2022 A Out  -200 800 
15/01/2022 A Out  -300 500 
16/01/2022 A In  3 1000 1500  2.00 
3/01/2022 A Out  -500 1000  2.00 
8/01/2022 B In  5 500 500 
10/01/2022 B Out  -100 400 
15/01/2022 B In  6 500 900  3.33 
18/01/2022 B Out  -200 700  3.33

Thanks

Comment: @DineshSuranga I cannot reproduce your problem of missing and incorrect avg prices. Works fine here (as shown in my screenshots). I have no idea what went wrong on your end. You'll need to look at what you did closely, and possibly supply more data.  And please **do not** paste textual data into a comment.  Have you looked at it and tried to paste it from your comment into an Excel table?  Maybe you have a special tool that I don't have? Paste the text into your question, and format it as you can see in other questions in this forum.

Comment: Hi Ron, There was an issue in my data. I corrected it and Now its working fine. I Really appreciate your help regarding this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. When asking, add sample data, not pictures.
2. Aggregations over the rows have to be done in **DAX**, not **PowerQuery**
3. You can use the **Quick measure** calulation *Running Total* to create your *Running Qty* column, using *Qty* as *Base value* and *Date* as *Field*

The measure you'll receive will look something like this:

```
Qty running total in Date = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Stock'[Qty]),
    FILTER(
        ALLSELECTED('Stock'[Date]),
        ISONORAFTER('Stock'[Date], MAX('Stock'[Date]), DESC)
    )
)
```

Note that in a visual you'll have to filter this measure by date (e.g. X-axis or first column of a table) to receive the desired numbers.

Comment: Date Material Type In Price Qty
1/01/2022 A In  2 1000
2/01/2022 A Out  -200
15/01/2022 A Out  -300
16/01/2022 A In  3 1000
3/01/2022 A Out  -500
8/01/2022 B In  5 500
10/01/2022 B Out  -100
15/01/2022 B In  6 500
18/01/2022 B Out  -200

Hi, This is the data. I have to calculate Running total and average unit cost by each material.
Thanks

Comment: Does it calculate running total for different materials separately?

Comment: I propose your check it out!

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you for your answer. I check that with my data but it did not help me to solve my problem. Thanks.